# python run two while loops concurrently

Tags: python

I am trying to make a wheel of fortune game, and trying to get both codes to run simultaneously 
the first while loop is to check whether it is a vowel or consonant, and the second while loop is to check whether the consonant is already picked previously

```
if currentguess in vowels:
        consonantcheck = False                
    while consonantcheck == False:
        currentguess = input('Not a consonant, please try again with a consonant: ')
        if currentguess not in vowels:
            consonantcheck = True

if currentguess in addedcons:
    consalreadyadded = False
while consalreadyadded == False:
    currentguess = input('The consonant is already guessed, pick another consonant: ')
    if currentguess not in addedcons:
        consalreadyadded = True
```

Comment: Why exactly do you need to run the two loops in parallel?

Comment: Can you add a MRE? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having two loops that both are dependent on conditions determined within their individual scopes, you can have one loop that you break out of when a condition is met.

```
while True:
   my_var = do_something()
   if my_var == 1 or my_var == 2:
       do_something_else()
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

For the purpose of making two validation checks against the same input you can use `if` and `elif` statements in an indefinite `while` loop and `break` only when the input passes all validations:

```
addedcons = set()
while True:
    while True:
        currentguess = input('Enter a consonant: ')
        if currentguess in 'aeiou':
            print('Not a consonant, please try again with a consonant.')
        elif currentguess in addedcons:
            print('The consonant is already guessed, pick another consonant.')
        else:
            addedcons.add(currentguess)
            break
    print('Consonants guessed so far:', ', '.join(sorted(addedcons)))
```

Demo: https://repl.it/@blhsing/UnwrittenSpanishInteger